# Jasmine Testing for Random Return of Array

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jasmine

I have this function that will randomly return a color:

```javascript
function setRandomColor() {
 var randomColor = ["red", "blue", "green", "#9CBA7F", "yellow", "#BF5FFF"];
 return randomColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length)];
}
```

I am new to Jasmine and have no idea how to go about testing this. Any ideas? I understand you can use `.toEqual` but the return value would be different every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bigger question. What are you trying to test? In other words what do you want to assert? Heres some examples:

1. The function returns a string.
2. The function returns only one of the strings in a list.
3. The function returns a specific string (deterministic).

If all you care is that the rest of your code can assume that the function will return a string but the actual value is not important because it's random then the first one is the best. If you are testing the function calculates a value correctly the the last one is the best.

In the case of the later you will have to mock the `Math.random()` to always return the same results. There are many libraries out there that handle this.

In the former case it's easy:

```
describe('#setRandomColor', function() {
  it('returns a string', function() {
    expect( setRandomColor() ).toEqual(jasmine.any(String));
  });
});
```

To be complete option 2 is more complicated and requires you to reference the original array of options to test against or to use dependency injection like @alex mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Sukima for the thorough answer. In this case, returns a string works fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Pass in an optional list of colors, then you can know the pool, in order to do an `indexOf()` with the returned value with your original list.